# Responsive with content boxes with full bleed right edge on main content block

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

Can anyone think how to achieve the below layout in CSS? I want the left column (box A) to be 1/3 of the space between the red lines, the right column (box B) to be 2/3 of the space between the red lines and then, when the screen is wider than than the red lines to have a white box extend all the way to the right edge of the screen (box C, although I imagine B will be inside C? Maybe not, that might be where I am going wrong). I'm using Tailwind but that shouldn't be an issue.

I've tried a few thing but what ever I do that left edge of B starts to overlap A and get messy.

Red lines don't exist in the site, that's just for reference here.

[image]

Comment: Two questions: does the space between the red lines has a width in pixels? Does the space on the left of the first red line has a width in pixels?

Comment: @kenshuri its responsive so no, the main content is always centred and the red lines width jumps at break points

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements. Please have a look at [proposed implementation on tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/xSPgnMnZSk) and share feedback. If all good, I'll make it an answer explaining the different concepts used in the process.